# Is it possible to display the Google Chrome browser from within an Android app?

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-intent

I want my app to launch chrome but also monitor the user's actions on chrome, such as navigating, back, etc. I think I can launch chrome using Intents, but I'm not sure about monitoring user input.

Comment: Check [this](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs)

Comment: Thanks, I did, but Custom Tabs won't do what I want. See my comments below.

Answer (score 1):

With chrome application is not possible. For do that you must implement a webview within your own app.

Comment: I'm writing an Android app, not a Chrome app; besides, Chrome apps are no longer supported.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can try [Custom Tabs](https://developers.google.com/web/android/custom-tabs)

With Custom Tabs you can get instance of browser which support CustomTabs like chrome without creating a web view. As it provide navigation awareness, the browser delivers a callback to the application upon an external navigation. You can modify and update following -

> Custom menu
>
> Color of the address bar
>
> Custom action button
>
> Custom enter and exit animations

Check [Custom Tabs Implementation Guide](https://developers.google.com/web/android/custom-tabs/implementation-guide)

Comment: Thanks for the link, Nikhil. I read through it, as well as the link to Progressive Web Apps, and I don't think either will give me the level of control I'm looking for. The more I examine the problem, the more I'm coming to the conclusion that I need to write a Chrome Extension, rather than a mobile app.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Web view or create your own browser then you can achieve your goal.

Comment: That's the point: I want to present to the user the familiar Chrome browser, not a home-brewed one.